# Resized sprite doesn't display

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to resize an image based on the screen height and I'm running into trouble. Currently the problem is that the image simply isn't displaying. Here is the code:

```
class Board
{
    private Texture2D texture;
    private int screenWidth = Game1.Instance.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
    private int screenHeight = Game1.Instance.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
    private Vector2 location;
    private Rectangle destination;

    public Board(Texture2D texture)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.location = new Vector2(200, 0);
        this.destination = new Rectangle((int)location.X, (int)location.Y, texture.Width * (screenHeight / texture.Height), screenHeight);
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture,
                        destination,
                        Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
```

The image has displayed before, albeit still too wide, so I know that the code within the main loop is fine. So my question in short is... What's wrong with this code and is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
texture.Width * (screenHeight / texture.Height)
```

Is using integer division. If the texture is bigger than the screen, it will return 0. With a width of 0, you won't see the texture. Instead, cast one operand to `double` or `float`:

```
texture.Width * (screenHeight / (double)texture.Height)
```

Will return a `double`, allowing the division/multiplication to work as you expected.

Comment: Not a problem. Integer division, especially when working with framework classes, can be hard to spot.